# jQuery get title attribute of html link

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery snippet which looks for the div with the classes **"selector-options my-wrapper selected"**

```
<div class="selector-options my-wrapper selected">
    <a class="my_anchor" title="This is my link title" href="www.myexample.com">
        My Link
    </a>
</div>

jQuery(window).load(function()
    {
        jQuery( ".elector-options.my-wrapper.selected" ).css( "border", "1px solid blue" );
    });
```

This is working great but now I would like to save the **.my_anchor** link **title attribute** within the specific div as a variable.

Anyone got a example of something similar I can see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the anchor element is the only one with that class, this should work:

```
var title = $('.selector-options.my-wrapper.selected > .my_anchor').attr('title');
```

If it's not the only one, you should use an id.

This assumes the anchor is a direct child of `.selector-options.my-wrapper.selected`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myVar = $('.selector-options.my-wrapper.selected').find('.my_anchor').attr('title');
```

Comment: I am looking to target the specific .my_anchor within the div.  Will make OP clearer

Comment: I don't understand, are there multiple .my_anchor elements? if so how do you know which one you're trying to target?

Comment: There isn't multiple .my_anchor elements in the example I have given but I am looking to target the .my_anchor within the given div

Comment: class selector always return arry

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
var title = "";
$(".my_anchor").on("click", function(e){
  title = $(this).attr("title");
  alert(title);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selector-options my-wrapper selected">
    <a class="my_anchor" title="This is my link title" href="www.myexample.com">
        My Link
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This will work but not sure if OP needs the value before a click event or not